# my switch statement keeps returning undefined. what

Tags: javascript

```js
function tipCalculator(bill) {
  switch (bill) {
    case (bill < 50):
      return bill * 0.2;
    case (bill >= 50) && (bill < 200):
      return bill * 0.15;
    case (bill > 100):
      return bill * 0.2
    default:
      console.log('this statement is empty');
  }
};

console.log(tipCalculator(125));
```

it keeps returning undefined. stack overflow is asking me to add more text but the problem here really speaks for itself so im just gonna run this one out. please help obi wan

Comment: your func doesn't return a value on default, put it outside switch

Comment: Switch looks for a case that *matches the argument*, not a case that evaluates to true.

Comment: That's not how switch statement work. You have to give it a value `case 5:` not an expression.

Comment: try `switch(true) { case bill < 50:` etc

Answer (score 3):

Your switch statement doesn't do what you think it does either: switches enumerate values (cases). You're merely using if-then logic in a switch. `case (bill < 50)` evaluates to `case false`, which is not equal to `125`, and so it skips that. This occurs with each case, since the cases are using expressions, rather than actual values.

Since the default statement is the only one that can possibly occur, and it returns no value, this switch will always return undefined.

You likely want code as follows:

```
function tipCalculator(bill) {
    if (bill < 50) {
        return bill * 0.2;
    } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200) {
        return bill * 0.15;
    } else if (bill > 100) {
        return bill * 0.2;   
    } else {
        throw new Error('Unknown bill.')
    }
};

console.log(tipCalculator(125));
```

Comment: or `switch(true) { case bill < 50:` etc

Comment: @JaromandaX True, but I doubt they want to switch on a boolean condition. If/then statements are much more logical here.

Comment: sure - just throwing in an alternative that does use switch :p

Comment: Yeah it definitely does work, it just feels... unidiomatic :D.

Comment: Where `bill > 100` and `bill < 200` it satisfies both the second and third *if* expressions, but will never reach the third block.

Comment: probably a typo in the original code